# Ubuntu: starting firefox from java started in /X11/Xsession.d is running but not visible

Tags: java, linux, firefox, ubuntu, x11

I have a script in my Ubuntu Linux directory /etc/X11/Xsession.d/98start which looks like this to start a diagnostic Java application:

```
nohup /usr/bin/java -jar /opt/diagnostics/diagnostic.jar /opt/diagnostics 2>> /dev/null >> /dev/null &
```

Within this application a number of things are checked and after it receives some commands from a server (less then 10 seconds) it starts the browser with this command:

```
firefox http://10.0.0.1:8080/client.html
```

The problem is that firefox starts correctly, "ps aux" shows that it is running, but nothing is visible on the screen.

When I kill the firefox process, the Java application restarts it, and then it is visible. So it looks like the first start is "too fast" and firefox is running somewhere in the background or on an other level then X11...

Also adding --display to the start command has no success

```
firefox http://172.24.17.10:8080/client/index.shtml --display :0.0
```

So maybe I should question these:

- Is X11 the correct place to start my Java application. I already use 98 to have it the last one, but maybe that's still to soon?
- Is their an other way to start firefox to force it to the foreground?

Thanks in advance for any help!
Frank

Comment: maybe it should be `firefox http://10.0.0.1:8080/client.html &` ?

Comment: unfortunately not... same strange behavior

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved by starting firefox twice...